# rustc throws an error when trying to use automatically provided into method over a reference

Tags: rust

Why `rustc` can not infer types in the following piece of code

```
struct Number {
    n: i32,
}

impl From<i32> for Number {
    fn from(n: i32) -> Self {
        Self { n }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let i = 5;
    let i_ref = &i;
    let m: Number = *i_ref.into();
    println!("{}", m.n);
}
```

It throws an error

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:14:28
   |
14 |     let m: Number = *i_ref.into();
   |                            ^^^^
   |
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
   |
14 |     let m: Number = *<&{integer} as Into<T>>::into(i_ref);
   |                      ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     ~
```

However, if I change line 14 to `let m: Number = (*i_ref).into();` the compiler is happy.

I thought that dereference always happens before method-call so I am not really sure why adding brackets helps here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that dereference always happens before method-call

You were misinformed. The precedence of the expression `*i_ref.into()` is `*(i_ref.into())`. So Rust tries to find an `Into<???>` instance for `i32`. But it doesn't know what goes in the `???`. It could be anything that implements `Deref<Target=Number>`.

On the other hand, when you write

```
let m: Number = (*i_ref).into();
```

We know `i_ref` is a reference to a number, so we know it derefs to an `i32` (Technically, all we know is `{integer}`, which is a sort of special case for integer literal overloading baked into the compiler. But that's not germane here). We also know the result should be a `Number`, so we want `Into<Number>` for `i32`. The blanket impl for `Into` tells us we want `From<i32>` for `Number`, which is an instance that exists.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "I thought that dereference always happens before method-call", you are probably misunderstanding how deref coerction works. Indeed, the deref coerction mechanism might, in certain situations, act *as if* you inserted a dereference operator before a method call and, in this situation, the dereference happens before the method call.

However, this has nothing to do with syntactic priority of a method call and the dereference operator. In your case, method call has higher priority, which means `*a.b()` will be parsed as `*(a.b())`, so you have to write out the parenthesis if you want it to be `(*a).b()`.